# Make better Haskell function

Tags: haskell

I have following Haskell function

```
fun::Vertex3 GLfloat -> Vertex3 GLfloat ->  Vertex3 GLfloat
fun (Vertex3 x0 y0 z0) (Vertex3 x1 y1 z1) = do sth here
        where
            p0 = (Vertex3 x0 y0 z0)
            p1 = (Vertex3 x1 y1 z1)
            p = p0 + p1
```

I'm wondering whether there is a way to **not repeat**
`(Vertex3 x0 y0 z0) (Vertex3 x1 y1 z1)` inside the code

I'm looking for some thing like:

```
fun::Vertex3 GLfloat -> Vertex3 GLfloat ->  Vertex3 GLfloat
fun p0 p1 = do sth here
    where 
        p0 = (Vertex3 x0 y0 z0)
        p1 = (Vertex3 x1 y1 z1)
        p = p0 + p1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use an [*as-pattern* [AGItH'98]](https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/patterns.html):

```
fun::Vertex3 GLfloat -> Vertex3 GLfloat -> Vertex3 GLfloat
fun p0@(Vertex3 x0 y0 z0) p1@(Vertex3 x1 y1 z1) = do sth here
        where p = p0 + p1
```

Here we thus have a reference to both the argument `p0`, as well as elements in the data constructor (`x0`, `y0`, `z0`).

These *as-patterns* can be used at different levels in the pattern.

Comment: @AronLee: I would use as-patterns, but you could also use pattern-matching, with code similar to what you wrote in your question: `fun p0 p1 = … where { Vertex3 x0 y0 z0 = p0; Vertex3 x1 y1 z1 = p1; p = p0 + p1 }`. You just had the expression `pN` and the `Vertex3 …` pattern swapped. This is an *irrefutable* pattern, and is safe if `Vertex3` is the only constructor, so the match can’t fail.